# All gallery images are being displayed by Fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using the fancy box 2, but when I click on the link to open the slideshow, all the images are shown at once. Sometimes it will add a scroll bar....see code below

http://jsfiddle.net/Tx3AF/

Sorry I couldnt add the fancyboox JS to show the gallery..
Any help will be appreciated...I have searched on the internet and no luck...

Thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle link you gave doesn't include the fancybox js. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using this

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none'
});​
```

then just add the `class` fancybox to all `<a>` tags that target an image of the same gallery.

Your first link

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#morephotos">This shows ...
```

should actually target the first image of the gallery

```
<a class="fancybox" href="firstImage.jpg" rel="gallery">This shows....
```

... otherwise will show whatever is inside the `<div>` with `id="morephotos"`.

Don't forget to wrap your custom fancybox script within the .ready() method like

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none'
    });​ // fancybox
  }); // ready
```